# Report preview cannot find Data source folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2008-r2, ssdt-bi

When I try to preview report in Visual Studio 2012 Designer I am getting an error:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
An error occurred during local report processing.
Error in the application.

Could not find a part of the path '...\bin\Debug\Data Sources\SomeDatasource.rds'.
```

Couple remarks:

1. There is a valid data source in project.
2. When I build project it creates flat (no folders) structure of reports, datasets and datasources in bin\Debug folder
3. Data Source folder (along with other folders) is defined for deployment only
4. When I removed folders in deployment settings, it is still not working
5. It might be related to installing the latest SSDT (11.1.40403.0) yesterday... however right after installing everything worked
6. Everything worked in this configuration so far...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) open the report definition's xml by right click -> view code

2) browse to Report -> DataSources -> DataSourceReference

3) replace "/Data Sources/MyDS" with "MyDS"

This clearly should have been patched by now!

Comment: Yes, this was indeed a problem.

Comment: This is so frustrating! There are so many different articles too and this was the solution.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error on deployment because the .rds file was not yet made in the deployment folder. My data source was under Shared Data Sources. I fixed it by building the .rds file in Visual Studio like so.

1. Right click on .rds file in question.
2. Click Build

[image]

This creates the .rds file in the folder that is being used for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I created a "Data Sources" folder under .../bin/Debug/ , and copied the data source items into it. I tried the above but this is what solved it for me. (SSDT 2017, working with SQL 2014 SSRS files )